# Diseño responsive

Tags: bootstrap

De que forma podría en un diseño responsibe, tener una 3 imagenes una al lado de la otra (podría ser dentro de un div cada una) y que al cambiar el ancho de pantalla la imagen cambia  de medidas auto **pero no se me baje una debajo de la otra cuando el ancho es menor a las 3 med ** es decir quede una al lado de la otra

```css
.ob {display: inline;}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="ob"><img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" /></div>
 <div class="ob"><img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" /></div>
 <div class="ob"><img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" /></div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ob{
   display: inline-block;
   width: calc(100% / 3);
}
.ob img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

De esta manera, los contenedores de la imágenes se ubicaran en línea, ocupando siempre un tercio del ancho total cada uno, independientemente al tamaño de la pantalla. En tanto, las imágenes ocuparán el 100% del tamaño de sus respectivos contenedores

**EDITADO**

`display: inline-block` creará un espaciado entre las imágenes, ese exceso hará que la última imagen se desplace hacia abajo `float: left` hará el mismo efecto pero sin el espaciado, por lo que no desplazará la imagen hacia abajo.

```
.ob{
   float: left;
   width: calc(100% / 3);
}
.ob img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: hay alguna formas de alinear esas imagenes middle, el text aling ni el vertical align me sirve, tampoco el margin auto, agradecería tu ayuda

Comment: Hola @Daniel, si lo que quieres es que los `img` queden centrados uno debajo del otro, este es el código: `.ob{ display:block; width: 33.3%; margin: 0 33.3% 2% 33.3% } .ob img{ width: 100%; }`

Comment: Hola @MichelEscalanteÁlvarez gracias por tu respuesta, me gustaría que las imágenes queden una al lado de la otra pero alineadas todas por la linea media de cada imagen 
en este codigo como haria eso
 `<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 footer_c color3">
<div>
<img src="instagram.png" /></div><!--
--><div>
<img src="facebook.png" />
</div><!--
--><div>
<img src="twitter.png" />
</div>
</div>

.footer_c div {
 display: inline-block;
 width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.footer_c img{
width: 100%;
}
`
  las imagenes originales tienen diferentes ancho pero with 100% para responsibe

Comment: @Daniel, con el siguiente código puedes lograr lo que necesitas: `<style>img {vertical-align:middle;}</style>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 footer_c color3"> 
<img src="instagram.png" />
<img src="facebook.png" />
 <img src="twitter.png" />
 </div>`

Answer (score 2):

Debes agregar lo siguiente en la sección del *CSS*:

```
div, img{
    width:100%;
}
.ob{
    display: inline;
    width: 33.3%!important
}
```

Esto hace que los `div` y las imágenes `img` ocupen todo el ancho de su contenedor (para el caso de el `div` sería la pantalla y para las `img` el ancho del `div` de clase `ob` que la contiene ). Además, todos los elementos que tengan la clase `ob`, tienen un tercio del ancho (1/3 = 0.333, es decir el 33.3%). El atributo `inline` hace que no haya un espacio horizontal entre un párrafo y otro.

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando bootstrap(lo digo por la etiqueta de la pregunta), puedes usar las [grids de bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) para mantener las 3 imágenes en la misma altura.

Ahora en la imagen puedes usar la clase [`img-responsive`](http://www.oneskyapp.com/es/docs/bootstrap/css#images-responsive) para que tenga un ancho de 100% y una altura automática según el elemento padre. Si la imagen no se expande correctamente, puedes aplicar una regla para la imagen que tenga un ancho del 100%

Ejemplo:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    texto alguno
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">Texto alguno</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">Texto alguno</div>
</div>
```

Comment: tengo un row y 3 div hijos col-xs-6 col-xs-3 y col-xs-3. Podria convertir esas col-xs-* (añadir row)  en padres y tener de hijos unas col-xs-*?
El ejemplo el div padre de la pregunta es un div row con hijos col

Comment: @Daniel he modificado la respuesta, no se si eso es lo que me tratas de comentar

Comment: Si mas o menos asi, esa podria ser una solucion, pero solo para aclarar la pregunta era si podia usar la en el mismo <div class"col-xs-6 row"> div hijos col- ..... </div>
la clase row y col-xs-*

Comment: @Daniel si se puede, pero por buenas practicas no se recomienda, lo mejor es  hacerlo como lo puse en la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta

Comment: @Daniel si la respuesta te ha servido no olvides marcarla como aceptada, si bien también consideras que es de utilidad puedes votarla

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo usas bootstrap, aquí tienes un ejemplo. En dispositivos tipo smartphone y tablet (xs y sm) ocupan todo el espacio disponible mientras que en desktop (md y lg) ocupan una tercera parte.

La imágenes tienen estilos para que ocupen todo el ancho disponible aunque le pongas menos.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<main>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <img class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12 img-responsive" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <img class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12 img-responsive" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <img class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12 img-responsive" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```